# How to install page.js

Tags: javascript, npm

I want to use [page.js](http://visionmedia.github.com/page.js/) in my project. But I think its using some sort of build system so I am not getting a single page.js file that I include in the page and start using

```
page('/',index)
```

Any idea, how to use it.

Comment: In the same directory, use command `npm install page`

Comment: @RayShih you where 2 seconds faster than me to answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

In your terminal:

```
npm install page
```

Then in node:

```
> var page = require('page')
undefined
> page
{ [Function: page]
  callbacks: [],
  base: [Function],
  start: [Function],
  stop: [Function],
  show: [Function],
  replace: [Function],
  dispatch: [Function],
  Context: [Function: Context],
  Route: [Function: Route] }
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

The actual client-side script is called `index.js` in the root directory of the bundle. Just rename it to `page.js` and copy it to wherever you're keeping your library scripts.

Comment: Renaming maybe not a good idea, unless it's done within his build pipeline, so when the package updates he'd automatically use the newer one. If it's not the build pipeline, he should just reference into the bundle instead of renaming.